# Why number 10_000_000_000 in JS becomes 1410065408 in webassembly?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, assemblyscript

I made a very simple wasm with the following text format. The function just return the i32 parameter.

```
(module
 (type $i32_=>_i32 (func (param i32) (result i32)))
 (memory $0 0)
 (export "sum" (func $assembly/index/sum))
 (export "memory" (memory $0))
 (func $assembly/index/sum (param $0 i32) (result i32)
  local.get $0
 )
)
```

and use the export function in nodejs:

```
const mod = await (...load wasm here)
console.log(mod.sum(10_000_000_000));   //1410065408
```

why it outputs 1410065408?

Comment: maximum value of defined integer, if you need higher you use int64, which is larger which often makes things more complex

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're usiung an `i32` as a parameter, which has a max value of `2147483647`, and you're passing in `10000000000`. It's either truncating or overflowing the value to fit inside an integer.

I suggest using an `i64` if your use case truly needs to handle numbers this big

Answer (score 1):

*(Jam is right. Just filling in the tedious details)*

Wasm's `i32` type is 4 bytes. (4*8)

10_000_000_000<sub>10</sub> is 2_540B_E400<sub>16</sub> (or 0x2540BE400) and that's 5 bytes, so JavaScript silently truncates it to 4 bytes (the leading `2_` is lost) when passing it to the Wasm function.

So we get 540B_E400<sub>16</sub> which is 1_410_065_408<sub>10</sub> which is exactly the result you are seeing.